# Special Characters line ' are not displayed in text box of html form

Tags: php, html, input

I want to show a predefined value in the text box which may contain special characters like `'` i.e. single quote e.g. Amit's Birthday.... When I am displaying the string it shows only Amit and omitted the further string. I used `htmlspecialchars()` function as I am using PHP but its not happening result is still same. Somebody please Help me with this .

Comment: use ENT_QUOTES as 2nd param for htmlspecialchars. if output is encoded string then replace with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

from server side send data as html encoded with htmlspecialschars

```
<?php
   $new = htmlspecialchars("Amit's Birthday", ENT_QUOTES);
   echo $new; // Amit&#039;s Birthday;
?>
```

if your setting value attribute on server side then it will be encoded string with ***& # 0 3 9;*** inplace of single quote and same for if you are doing it on client side with ajax call for fetching data.

Put id, name or class attribute of your input field then write this code on document on  load function or when you have input field filled with required data.

```
   // < input class="decodeIt" type="text" value="Amit&#039;s Birthday" />    

    var decodedValue = $(".decodeIt").val().replace("&#039;", "'");
    $(".decodeIt").val(decodedValue );
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manual: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

> ''' (single quote) becomes ''' only when ENT_QUOTES is set.

So either delimit your attribute values with double quotes, instead of single, or set ENT_QUOTES (as per Example 1 on the page linked above).